# coqide - can't load modules from same folder

Tags: coq

I can't load modules that are in same folder in CoqIde.

I'm trying to load sources from Software Foundations, I'm running coqide in folder that contains SF sources with `coqide` or `coqide ./`, then after opening and running the file, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Cannot find library Poly in loadpath
```

in this line:

```
Require Export Poly.
```

and it's same for every other `require` commands.

So how are you people loading programs from SF into coqide ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to compile the .v files into .vo files and add their directory to your load path if you're going to require them. To compile them, run `coqc <file-path>` in the command prompt. To add the files' directory to your load path in CoqIde, you can insert the line `Add LoadPath "<directory-path>".` at the beginning of the .v files.

Comment: Is there a Coq load path environment variable?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Yes, COQPATH: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual016.html#sec587

Comment: it says `LoadPath` is not valid syntax `Syntax error: illegal begin of vernac.`

Comment: you need `Add` see answer bellow.

Comment: On later versions of Coq you have to add also a suffix "as ...", like:
`Add LoadPath "/Users/myuser/cpdt/src" as Cpdt.`

Answer (score 7):

I realize this is an old thread, however there are not many resources on this problem. I just spent some time solving it so I figured it would be good to post it on the first topic I got from googling. I'm using Coq 8.4p16 compiled with no additional configuration on Arch Linux.

So, the manual says variables like `$COQPATH, ${XDG_DATA_DIRS}/coq/` and `${XDG_DATA_HOME}/coq/` are checked, however I've had no luck with those.

I also tried putting `coqc -I /folder/path` the `Edit->Preferences->Externals` of CoqIde, however, still no luck there.

I write these as they may work for someone.

The only GLOBAL way which works for me is writing a coqrc file with `Add LoadPath "<directory-path>".` in it. On Linux the file needs to be in the home folder.

Hope this saves someone some time.

Comment: This works if you are using coqIDE (command line always works). I wish coqIDE would automatically add current PWD to the load path but it's not.

Comment: It seems there might be a way to get this to work using _CoqProject, but I'm not sure how:
http://coq-club.inria.narkive.com/q5jGTrgk/configuring-coqide-using-coqproject

Comment: The same for me: the only way `coqc cli tool`works is using coqrc file, but I'm under x64 win7 for coq 8.6 December 2016.

Answer (score 4):

To be able to load a source file in coqtop, coqc, CoqIDE, or Proof General there are several ways, one method is as follows:

Suppose you have downloaded code files for the book titled *Certified Programming with Dependent Types* written by Adam Chlipala that are available [here](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) and extract them in a path we call CODEHOME. As you can see there are this first line in any source files `Require Import Bool Arith List Cpdt.CpdtTactics.`

First type `coqc -v` in a cli (command line interface), the output would be something like `The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.4pl4 ....`, then create a file named ***coqrc.8.4pl4***, the file extension should be in accord with the version of the coq you are using, in $HOME/.config/coq directory if it does not exist and write this line in it `Add LoadPath "CODEHOME/cpdt/src" as Cpdt .` and that's it.

Answer (score -1):

If you started your `file.v` with `Module file.` just get rid of it (Also get rid of the `End file.`) and your problem is solved.