# How to create a bibliography source file in coq

Tags: coq

I want to create a file bibliography in coq, i have a model of an automaton,

```
Record automaton :Type:=
   mk_auto {
       states : Set;
       actions :Set;
       initial : states;
       transitions : states -> actions -> list states
     }.

(*States*)
Inductive st :Set:= q0 | q1 | q2.

(*Actions*)
Inductive acts:Set:= a | b | c.

(*Transitions*)
Definition trans (q:st)(x:acts) :list st :=
match q, x with
     | q0, a =>  cons q1 nil
     | q1, b =>  cons q0 nil
     | q1, c =>  cons q2 nil
     | _,_ =>    nil (A:=_)
end.

 (* Automate A1 *)
 Definition A1 := mk_auto st acts q0 trans.
 Print A1.
```

I want to use the record model in different files.

```
Record automaton :Type:=
mk_auto {
    states : Set;
    ctions :Set;
    initial : states;
    transitions : states -> actions -> list states
}.
```

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "bibliography" file, but if you want to make a library that you can `Import` from other file, you just have to make a `.v` file with your Record definition, and compile it with `coqc`. It will create a `.vo` file that you can reuse through the `Require Import your_file.` scheme. 
You can put the `.vo` file in the same folder as your current `.v` file, or refer to the documentation to add search path to Coq (`Add LoadPath` if I remember correctly).

Cheers,
V.

EDIT: after your comment, here is my attempt at building the library, it might help you check what goes wrong:

```
vinz@####:/tmp/foo$ cat test.v
Record automaton :Type:= mk_auto {
    states : Set;
    actions :Set;
    initial : states;
    transitions : states -> actions -> list states
}.
vinz@####:/tmp/foo$ ls
test.v
vinz@####:/tmp/foo$ coqc test.v
vinz@####:/tmp/foo$ ls
test.glob  test.v  test.vo
```

EDIT2: if the `.vo` file is in the same directory as the `.v` you are currently editing, `coqide` seems to be happy. The general scheme is to write `Add Loadpath "/path/to/the/vo/file".` before the `Require Import`. This should cover your last issue

Comment: I try with that, by it does not work, i make two files in the same directory, the frist file is automod.v .

    Record automaton :Type:=
    mk_auto {
       states : Set;
       actions :Set;
       initial : states;
       transitions : states -> actions -> list states
    }.
And the second file is auto.v.

    Require Import automod.
I compile the first one, the file automod.vo is creating.
but it does not work ?!.
the message is:
Error: Cannot find library automod in loadpath.

Comment: You need to start your ``coqide/coqtop`` in the same directory where you compiled the ``.vo`` file. If you start it from another location, you have to tell Coq where to look, with the ``LoadPath`` vernacular. Please read the documentation or check SO for related issues, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202666/coqide-cant-load-modules-from-same-folder for example.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, the code is working now :)

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Do not forget to validate the answer to tag the question as "solved".