# Coq error: The reference evenb was not found in the current environment

Tags: coq

I'm trying to go through the Software Foundations Coq book (http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/toc.html), but when I compile Induction.v (which looks like http://www.cs.uml.edu/~rhenniga/coq/sf_induction.html), I get the error message "Error: The reference evenb was not found in the current environment." -- even after compilation of Basics.v. Any ideas why?

Comment: We need some more context to know what could be wrong. Are you using CoqIDE? Is Basics.v on the same directory as Induction.v? Is the compiled file Basics.vo actually showing up on that directory?

Comment: Try prepending `Add LoadPath "."` at the beginning of `Induction.v` as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16203673/596361).

Comment: I got `Error: The reference lia was not found in the current environment.` -- how does one fix that?

Answer (score 3):

> I can confirm that opening CoqIDE from the same directory works on macOS: `cd <sf-dir>; /Applications/CoqIDE_8.5.app/Contents/MacOS/coqide`

from: [The reference "X" was not found in the current environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129401/the-reference-x-was-not-found-in-the-current-environment)

Comment: I got `Error: The reference lia was not found in the current environment.` -- how does one fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Try to erase every blank character in the address related to Coq or software-foundation book.

In my case, when I struggled with the file

> C:\Users\XxX\Documents\software foundation\lf\Induction.v

, CoqIDE failed to execute `From LF Require Export Basics` and to define `evenb_S` theorem. Also, I couldn't see any files like `Basics.vo` or `Basics.glob` created when `Basics.v` with [Compile] - [Compile buffer] function in CoqIDE.

Everything works fine when I change my folder name to

> C:\Users\XxX\Documents\softwarefoundation\lf\Basic.v

The Coq installer had already informed this >> 
[Link to the screenshot image of Coq setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twEC5.png)

Comment: I got `Error: The reference lia was not found in the current environment.` -- how does one fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Compiling `Basic.v` with `coqc Basics.v` command should produce `Basic.vo` and `Basic.glob` files in the same directory. Then you should be fine with compiling `Induction.v` in the same directory as well; `coqc Induction.v`.