# The reference "X" was not found in the current environment

Tags: coq, coqide

I'm using CoqIDE to complete the exercises in the Software Foundations book about Coq. I can successfully compile Basics.v, resulting in Basics.vo and Basics.glob in my directory. When I try to run Induction.v, it works. When I try to compile it, it complains about tons of missing references, such as `evenb` and `negb_involutive`. If I copy Basics.v contents into Induction.v it compiles, but obviously this is not the way to go.

This is not a duplicate of question [Coq error: The reference evenb was not found in the current environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381470/coq-error-the-reference-evenb-was-not-found-in-the-current-environment), as I have already done those things:

Compile Basics.v. Check if Basics.vo is in the directory. Now compile Induction.v. This last step fails.

Comment: I tried it just now (downloaded a fresh copy of SF and compiled from the menu inside CoqIDE) and I did not get any errors. Could you explain a little more what it is that you do?  Which Coq-version do you have? I have 8.5pl2.

Comment: I have solved everything inside Basics.v and Induction.v. I have the same version as you. Perhaps I should try compiling the "empty" versions instead. I'll report back.

Comment: @larsr I have downloaded the fresh copy too. I opened CoqIDE, opened Basics.v and then compiled it. This was successful. When I then opened Induction.v and tried to compile it, I got the same error as before. So even the fresh copy doesn't seem to compile on my system. I'm using Mac OS X El Capitan.

Comment: You must compile Basic.v to get Basic.vo which is imported ("required") by Induction.v. It defines evenb and negb_involutive.  What happens if you first compile the fresh Basic.v and then the fresh Induction.v ?

Comment: My previous comment describes it: evenb is apparently not defined correctly if I compile the fresh Basic.v and then the fresh Induction.v.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it gets imported...  I think it is a question of paths. In coqide you can add path substitutions in the menu "Tools->Coqtop Arguments".  From the command line you would say   `-R <path-to-sf> ""`    where the double quotes empty-string mean that you can import everything in path-to-sf without writing something before it, like `Require Basic.`  However, I don't know how to write that in coqide, because it treats the quotes litterally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have experienced this error myself. Try opening CoqIDE from the same directory where the Software Foundations files are, and compile from there.  If you're on Linux, just open a terminal, go to that directory, and type `coqide` there. I don't quite know how to do this on other systems, e.g. Mac OS, but I did notice that just opening the app through the icon makes it fail.

Comment: I can confirm that opening CoqIDE from the same directory works on macOS: `cd <sf-dir>; /Applications/CoqIDE_8.5.app/Contents/MacOS/coqide`

Comment: I also started coqide from the command line while inside the sf dir.

Comment: On Windows: Instead of opening CoqIde by itself, double-click one of the *.v files in the project directory.