# How does one import the lia tactic given that the omega tactic was reprecated in Coq?

Tags: coq

I got the error:

```
Error: The reference lia was not found in the current environment.
```

how do I fix it?

code:

```
Require Import Lia.

 Theorem t:
    forall n: nat, 1 + n > n.
 Proof.
 Show Proof.
 intro.
 Show Proof.
 lia.
 Show Proof.
 Qed.
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381470/coq-error-the-reference-evenb-was-not-found-in-the-current-environment

Comment: Which version of Coq are you using? You can check with `coqc --version` on a terminal.

Comment: I am using `8.11.0` @AnaBorges

Comment: Ok, I just realized you answered yourself. I was super confused because your *question* already includes the solution. I was afraid `Require Import Lia` was not working for you for some reason.

Comment: Note that according to the [Coq changelog](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/changes.html), `omega` was only deprecated in Coq 8.12 and removed in 8.14. If you are using an older version of Coq, you can still make use of it. However, even in 8.11 the recommendation was to switch to `lia`, and unless you have a very good reason I would recommend updating your Coq installation anyway (the latest is 8.15.2).

Comment: @AnaBorges thanks ana! Appreciate it. My code is sort of a silly debug example, so for me it doesn't matter, but I think your comment is useful to whoever is actually curious/need to know this. Will thus update my answer with your comment and credit. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `Require Import Lia.` at the top. e.g.

```
Require Import Lia.

 Theorem t:
    forall n: nat, 1 + n > n.
 Proof.
 Show Proof.
 intro.
 Show Proof.
 lia.
 Show Proof.
 Qed.
```

note this is a replacement for `Omega`

---

## Edit:

As Ana Borges kindly pointed out:

> Note that according to the [Coq changelog](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/changes.html), omega was only deprecated in Coq 8.12 and removed in 8.14. If you are using an older version of Coq, you can still make use of it. However, even in 8.11 the recommendation was to switch to lia, and unless you have a very good reason I would recommend updating your Coq installation anyway (the latest is 8.15.2).