# Unable to locate library

Tags: coq

The same Linux command succeeds in one environment while it fails in another:

```
$ coqtop -lv test.v -I Lib
```

The failure I am getting is under Debian stretch and Coq v8.5

```
$ uname -a
Linux front 4.8.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.7-1 (2016-11-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ coqtop -v
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.5 (June 2016)
compiled on Jun 9 2016 12:4:46 with OCaml 4.02.3
```

and the error message I am getting is:

```
Welcome to Coq 8.5 (June 2016)
Require Import libtest.
Error during initialization:
File "/home/user/dev/coq/test.v", line 1, characters 15-22:
Error: Unable to locate library libtest.
```

The environment under which the same command relating to the same source succeeds is:

```
$ uname -a 
Linux back 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19)x86_64 GNU/...

$ coqtop
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.4pl4 (July 2014)
compiled on Jul 27 2014 13:34:24 with OCaml 4.01.0
```

The successful outcome is as follows:

```
Welcome to Coq 8.4pl4 (July 2014)
Require Import libtest.

Coq <
```

So I am trying to figure out what is going on, hoping to get an answer from
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202666/coqide-cant-load-modules-from-same-folder) but to no avail.

For the sake of this question, I have reduced the source code to the simplest:

**test.v**

```
Require Import libtest.
```

**Lib/libtest.v**

```
<empty file>
```

In case this matters I have recompiled the (empty) library file `libtest.v` in each environment.

```
$ cd Lib
$ coqc libtest.v
$ cd ..
```

Any help is gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, the behaviour of `-I` changed between 8.4 and 8.5. In the changelog of Coq, we can find [an interesting line](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/cf8ecf83b5cc52f7ea73dc1d3af59bf03deff688/CHANGES#L786). As hinted in the changelog and as advised by the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40963145/5153939), you can use `-R` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much ! `coqtop -lv test.v -I Lib` can indeed be replaced by `coqtop -lv test.v -R Lib ''` or `coqtop -lv test.v -Q Lib ''`.

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me (I'm using Coq 8.5pl3).
Let's compile our library, putting it in the `Lib` namespace:

```
$ pwd
<...>/libtest-question
$ cd Lib
$ coqc -R . "Lib" libtest.v
$ cd ..
```

Then let's modify our `test.v`:

```
$ cat test.v
Require Import Lib.libtest.
```

and load it with

```
$ coqtop -R Lib Lib -l test.v
```

The `-Q` switch would work too, see the Reference manual's [§14.3.3](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual016.html#sec580) for more detail.

Comment: Thank you very much Anton ! I somewhat arbitrarily chose to validate the other answer as it is simpler. However, your answer is showing us how to introduce namespaces which is very useful.

Comment: Thank you! eponier's answer also shows when it all started :).